# Problem with IVP (PDE)

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I'm not very familiar with the Method of Characteristics for PDEs but have been reading up with several *.pdfs and YouTubes in the past few days. Despite that I got stuck on a relatively simple semi-linear Real World case.

The equation is for a heat transfer problem:

$$\frac{1}{v}u_t+u_x=-\alpha u$$

Initial data:
$$u(0,x)=u_0$$

where $u(t,x)$ is a reduced temperature ($u>0$), $t$ is time, $x$ is distance travelled through a pipe, $v$ is a flow velocity (*constant*) and $\alpha$ a *constant*.

The characteristics are:

$$\mathrm{d}x=v\mathrm{d}t=-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\alpha u}$$

Now I  need two find two functions, say $\phi$ and $\psi$, along the characteristics, so that:

$$\mathrm{d}\phi = \mathrm{d}\psi=0$$

I chose:

$$\phi=x-vt$$

and:

$$\psi=x+\frac{\ln u}{\alpha}$$

The implicit solution is then supposed to be (with $F$ an arbitrary function):

$$F(x-vt,x+\frac{\ln u}{\alpha})=0$$

But how to render this explicit? And how to apply the initial data?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the implicit function theorem, we can write too $f(x-vt)=x+\dfrac{\ln u}{\alpha}$ an expression making easier the imposing of the initial conditions, $u(0,x)=u_0$

$$f(x)=x+\dfrac{\ln u_0}{\alpha}$$

$$x-vt+\dfrac{\ln u_0}{\alpha}=x+\dfrac{\ln u}{\alpha}$$

So is, $u(t,x)=u_0e^{-\alpha vt}$

Comment: Thank you. Beautiful!